# Persistent filesystem access issues in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs

I'm dual booting Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and Windows 10 across two hard drives. Originally, if you try and access the Windows partition from Ubuntu, you get an error, but [disabling fast startup and hibernation fixes this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

After I received the Anniversary update to Windows 10, I still have the problem although I have confirmed that hibernation is off. The fast startup option has disappeared from the menu. I suspect a change to Windows in the Anniversary update has interfered with Ubuntu accessing the NTFS filesystem.

I have heard that the tool `ntfsfix` can remove the hiberfil.sys file and allow Ubuntu to access the partition, but after several users with considerable reputation expressed concern that this **could lead to data loss**, I don't think it should be considered the final answer.

How should I solve it?

*Side note: this would have been commented on the post linked above, but I lack the 50 reputation to comment there.*

Comment: I have the newest version of Windows 10, and the Fast Startup option is still there under `Change what the power button does`  in the power settings.